# not able to convert Uint8 typedarray to FLoat32 Array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have pointData which is Uint8Array of point data with the structure of each point is 20 bytes and x, y, z have offset of 0, 4, 8 and intensity is at offset of 16 and all are of 4 bytes.

The data is stored in Uint8Array with each point is in stride. I don't know if this will add value or not but wanted to give context.

The data is in Uint8Array and vertex attribute in shader does not accept Uint8 so i need to convert this to Float32 typed array.

When i do,

```
if (pointData.byteLength > 0) {
    console.log(pointData);
    const PointData_2 = new Float32Array(pointData.buffer);
}
```

I get this console log and error:

[image]

can anyone please help me figure out what is wrong and how can i do this.

What i want to do is 4 bytes of Uint8 to make FLoat32.

I also tried `FLoat32.from()` but it turned out it just make each element float instead of making 4 8 bits as float32.

Can anyone please help me and I have tried all i could find in internet.

Comment: Please edit your previous question instead of re-posting it

Comment: @Bergi i had already tried things posted in the answers that people tagged as an answer and people closed my question before i could add more details.

Comment: You can add more details even after the question is closed, if you show how you tried the suggested things and how they didn't work, the question will get re-opened